Node.js Debugger causes ECONNRESET
I have a Typescript application that I debug on my local machine.
I encountered some weird behavior when debugging this transpiled piece of code:
getRedHatUpdatesByIds(rhsaIds, tmConfig) {
    return tslib_1.__awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function* () {
        const url = `${this.urls.GET_RED_HAT_UPDATES}`;
        const urlToSend = http_request_1.HttpRequest.buildUrl(this.baseUrl, url);
        const response = yield http_request_1.HttpRequest.post(urlToSend, { rhsaIds }, { headers: context_metadata_1.ContextMetadata.secureHeaders(tmConfig) });
        return response.data;
    });
}

As you can understand the line:
yield http_request_1.HttpRequest.post(...)

sends an HTTP call to another microservice.
I saw that when I put a breakpoint in the line:
return response.data;

The code executes the HTTP call successfully. However, when I put the breakpoint in the line:
const response = yield http_request_1.HttpRequest.post(urlToSend, ...)

the behaviour changes.
The code reaches the breakpoint, and after I resume the code execution I get the error:

Error: Error occurred while trying to send request: read ECONNRESET

It's very surprising because I expect a seamless behavior in debugging mode.
Is it possible that putting the breakpoint in this line closed the connection between the client and the server?

" because I expect a seamless behavior in debugging mode." - you don't debug a standalone application but an application interacting with a remote system. Depending on what you exactly do after hitting the breakpoint  you might have introduced delays, which made the server close the connection - for example if the server expected the client to send the request within a specific time frame. ECONNRESET is not your client closing the connection, but the server.

I think I have a theory. I think that although that I expect that the execution of the code stop BEFORE the http call, it actually stops DURING the handshake of the HTTP call. The client freezed before it returns the response to the server and then the server throws ECONNRESET.

@CrazySynthax Did you get this figured out? I am facing a similar issue. I wonder if it has something to do with my VPN but I was curious if you found a fix.
